How to create a terminal-like python pipe?
Some programs emit colored text when their output is connected to a terminal, and non colored text when their output goes to a pipe.
Is there a way in Python to open a pipe to a subprocess such that the subprocess will 'think' that it's outputs is connected to a terminal and will emit colored text?
In my specific case, the a Python program that uses click.secho() for colored text output, and I believe that click uses os.isatty(fd) to determine if it's connected to a terminal.

The canonical answer to this type of question is to use a pty

Many programs support forcing color on/off with an environment variable. I'm not sure if click does or not.
